# Suppose all normal lines of a curve pass through a fixed point. Show that the trace is contained in a circle.

Tags: differential-geometry

I found the following problem:

> Suppose all normal lines of a curve pass through a fixed point. Show that the trace is contained in a circle.

I spent a lot of time thinking about this but couldn't find an answer. I looked for the answer in the book and it says:

> Differentiate $\alpha(s)=\lambda(s) n(s)= constant$

I am a bit confused: What is $\alpha$? Up to now, the book is using $\alpha$ to name a curve but here, it's doesn't seems to be the case.

Comment: They are assuming the fixed point is the origin. Now can you see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\alpha(s)$ be a point on the curve, then there is a scaling factor $\lambda(s)$ such that the quantity:

$$ \alpha(s) + \lambda(s) n(s)=c$$

Evaluates to the constant point at each point on the curve. Differentiating both sides,

$$ \alpha'(s) + \lambda'(s) n(s) +\lambda(s) n'(s)=0$$

We know $\alpha'(s),n'(s)$ is in the direction of unit tangent vector. Dot both side with $n(s)$:

$$ \lambda'(s)=0$$

Meaning $\lambda=C$

---

Answer (score 1):

Say that fixed point is the origin. The velocity vector $\alpha'(s)$ is perpendicular to the position vector $\alpha(s)$, that is
$$\langle \alpha'(s), \alpha(s) \rangle = 0$$
or
$$\|\alpha(s)\|^2=\langle \alpha(s), \alpha(s) \rangle = \textrm{const}$$